# Probability of sum $7$ when throwing two dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

In a $2$ dice throw, one after the other, how many results can there be?  Then, if for example we consider the sum of the dice values, how many different ways can we get the sum $7$ with the two dices and in turn what is the probability of having a sum of $7$?

Comment: I suggest you write a table having the score on the first throw across the top and the score on the second throw down the side. Then you can put entries in the table representing the sum, and you should see clearly what is going on. This kind of thing you get to understand by doing better than by being told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each dice can be 1...6 so you have $6\cdot6=36$ outcomes.

Sum 7 can come from 1-6, 2-5, 3-4, 4-3, 5-2, 6-1 (6 outcomes)

Probability of having a sum of 7 is $\frac{6}{36}=\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: I was still writing on it :)